# How are styles within div's made 'safer' (i.e. so they do not override parent styles)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am implementing an email client. One of the problems that I am facing is the fact that displaying the emails (i.e. the body of the email) may interrupt the styles of the general web application (not just the div).

Say I have a JS variable:

```
var element = $(data.bodyHTML);
$('div.result').html(element);
```

Where `data.bodyHTML` is the HTML content of the email body which contains the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div, p, span, a {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: black;
    }
    .test-div, .test-p, #test-strong {
        color: blue !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test-div"><p class="test-p">Signature</p><strong id="test-strong">John Doe</strong></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `div, p, span, a` style destroys the styling in the rest of the web app (as long as I remain on the same page).

I've tried everything to prevent it from happening. I can't use an iFrame. I seen other email clients doing something like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .SafeStyles div, .SafeStyles p, .SafeStyles span, .SafeStyles a {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: black;
    }
    .SafeStyles .test-div, .SafeStyles .test-p, .SafeStyles #test-strong {
        color: blue !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="SafeStyles">
    <div class="test-div"><p class="test-p">Signature</p><strong id="test-strong">John Doe</strong></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

.SafeStyles is placed in front of each style tag/class/id so as to prevent any override to the parent.

But how is this being done? That is my question.

Any kind of help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I think people here seem to misunderstanding my question. I know exactly why the styles are overriding the parent, I know enough CSS to understand the basics. The question is this:

Given a string of html in javascript, with javascript, how do you add classes before the styles within the style tag of the given html string?

Comment: Uh, are you really going to display arbitrary html emails? If you actually need to, use an iframe - not because of styling, but because of security issues. Otherwise, just go for plain text like a normal email.

Comment: Go read http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82766/how-to-safely-display-html-emails-like-gmail-does-it

Comment: @a.j true and false. Many do use iframes. If you're comparing to gmail, then you're correct. However, I'd mention Google spent tens of millions of dollars, ten years, and dozens of developers to build Gmail. They have 100,000+ lines of code to make what you want work properly. It's not something you're going to get a simple answer here for. If it were me, I'd use an iframe.

Comment: I appreciate bergi's advice and that link has proven useful. Bergi if you see this, maybe you can post an actual answer so I can vote you. In the beginning (before people on here seemed to be giving me pep talks or child basics of CSS) I was looking for an answer that would tell me what other email clients are doing to get the desired behavior (overriding CSS classes), and yours was the closest to this. Thank you.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement/scoped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, given how CSS works: CSS doesn't care about where it's declared, it kicks in globally. If you have a rule `div { ... }` then that applies to all divs, everywhere in the document, and the only way to change what they do is to override properties with more specific rules.

And that's exactly what you do with `div.classname`: this does **not** apply to all divs, only to divs with a class `classname`. Want to be absolutely safe: add your own safety class(es) to each element, and declare CSS with selectors that rely on those:

```
<div class="personal safety">
  <p class="personal safety">
  </p>
</div>
```

and now we define the styles we want for these elements:

```
div.personal.safety { ... }
p.personal.safety { ... }
```

done, this CSS will only apply to our code.

Except only "sort of",  because if you use this on a page that happens to already use "personal safety" as CSS classes, then you still end up with a conflict. The usualy trick is to come up with classes that are specific enough to your use that they won't collide.

And then the second problem of course is that any CSS value you don't explicitly set, you will keep inheriting from the owning document so if there's this in the owning document:

```
div { background: red }
```

and you use this for your specific snippet content:

```
div.personal.safety { font-family: fantasy }
```

then that will lead to your snippet content being a red div with fantasy font. Because you didn't change the background color for your snippet HTML.

This is all essentially "the basics of CSS" so I'd also strongly urge you to read up on how CSS works. Read an O'Reily book, or google for some tutorials (not w3schools or MDN examples of individual CSS rules, but proper "learn CSS" tutorials).

And read the links you got in the comments: security is no laughing matter, *get that part right*.

Comment: I think you will find that you absolutely can, given what you described. If you get the data in via JS, then you can do absolutely anything you like to it before injecting it. Which is all the more reason to take security seriously.

Answer (score 0):

RE the Javascript question:

```
$('div.result').html(element).parent().addClass('safestyles');
```

Also, this look like jQuery rather than generic JS, so I've given a jQuery answer.

If you have nested BODY tags, which your post implies, then the BODY tag of the app might be conflicting with the BODY tag of the email itself.

Try putting the emails inside a DIV, and style that DIV.

RE the .safestyles class: it appears you are defining the style in the stylesheet, but not assigning that style to anything in your HTML.

Try:

```
<body>
    <div class="SafeStyles">
        <div class="test-div"><p class="test-p">Signature</p><strong id="test-strong">John Doe</strong></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As per @humble.rumble suggestion, my proposed solution assumes the OP has nested BODY tags (one from the app, and one from the email itself). Is that a correct assumption?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you understand [Specificity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiPnauYs5XGAhULNYgKHeBMDuc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2FSpecificity&ei=mrWAVY_oFovqoATgmbm4Dg&usg=AFQjCNHG_f6LtVjuZJ7_0REyqI-uHMz0bQ&sig2=p28kdv9akgI0vcyrD0qV3A&bvm=bv.96041959,d.cGU) and [Selectors](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDEQFjACahUKEwiKovHSs5XGAhWKpYgKHfZaDzU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FGuide%2FCSS%2FGetting_started%2FSelectors&ei=FbaAVcrDCYrLogT2tb2oAw&usg=AFQjCNExA3YVNYtuw9ZoGlgZCyeZrPh26A&sig2=TT5CS3YSk1iJIq4Xc2TRMw&bvm=bv.96041959,d.cGU) and then from your example, and then I'm guessing you could take 2 possible approaches: parsing the style source, either from HTML or CSS files, for all incoming content prepending a `SafeStyles.` to every CSS selector you find, thereby only allowing those rules to be set on elements inside of the div with that class, then displaying the new content wrapped in a div with `class="SafeStyles"`. Or the opposite, and protecting your own styles by increasing specificity on all them to the point where its unlikely they'd be overwritten I guess.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xLeewd2w/ << Example provided

your provided html code

```
var myhtml =
'<html><head><style>div, p, span, a {padding: 0;margin: 0;color: black;}.test-div,est-p,#test-strong {color: blue !important;}</style></head><body><div class="test-div"><p class="test-p">Signature</p><strong id="test-strong">John Doe</strong></div></body></html>';
```

remove the pesky !important tags

```
var newhtml = myhtml.replace(" !important", "");
```

this is where I set the html contents, change the id to your chosen container

```
var example = $("#parsedhtml");
```

I'll set the html in the container

```
example.html(newhtml);
```

and then alter the css going after the id of #test-strong, only within example.

```
$("#test-strong", example).css({"background-color": "#ffe", "border": "5px solid #ccc", "font-size": "30px", "color":"red", "float":"right"});
```

Comment: you are 100% right, I didn't understand, so I took the time to figure it out. See my answer for fiddle.